# Edit Particular Google Sheet from Android App

Tags: database, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm currently attempting to create an app which uses a Google Sheet as a database of users and subscription dates - I have found how to add new users to the database via hooking into Google Forms, however this does not let me edit the value of user subscription dates after they've already been set once, so I am trying to figure out how I could edit the sheet from within the app.
The problem is, that all information I can find on editing Google Sheets (all using the Sheets API) covers how to edit/create a sheet of the user, rather than the specific sheet of mine that I want to change (as far as I can tell)

Does anybody know how I can just edit my one specific sheet from within an Android app?

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete and verifiable code. Expound your question and share any error message if any. In the meantime, you may want to check the official documentation for [spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Comment: I haven't got any code yet as I am unable to find any info on how to to it - the site you linked also doesn't mention how to edit sheets.